# Many to Many and Linq: updating relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

So I've got three tables (well, 2 tables and 1 mapping table) as follows:

```
dbo.Catalog
    CatalogID // int [not null] autoincrement PK
dbo.Product
    ProductID // int [not null] autoincrement PK
dbo.CatalogProductMap
    CatalogID // int [not null] PK
    ProductID // int [not null] PK
```

I have checkboxes on a page for updating a `Product` like so:

```
<% foreach(var catalog in dataContext.Catalogs){ %>
    <!-- add a checkbox for each catalog  -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="catalog[<%= catalog.CatalogID %>]" />
<% } %>
```

In my code for processing the POST I have:

```
 // Regex to check Form keys and group each ID
 var rCatalog = new Regex("^catalog\\[(\\d+)\\]$");
 // gets all "checked" CatalogIDs POSTed
 IEnumerable<int> checkedCatalogs =
            Request.Form.AllKeys
                   // get only the matching keys...
                   .Where(k => rCatalog.IsMatch(k))
                   // and select the ID portion of those keys...
                   .Select(c => int.Parse(rCatalog.Match(c).Groups[1].Value));
```

**And then this smelly part:**

### UPDATED!

*Thanks to [Dave Swersky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089608/many-to-many-and-linq-updating-relationships#answer-4089681) for the `Any<>` method*

```
Product Product = getProductBeingUpdated();

// iterate through each EXISTING relationship for this product
// and REMOVE it if necessary.
myDataContext.CatalogProductMaps
    .DeleteAllOnSubmit(from map in Product.CatalogProductMaps
        where !checkCatalogs.Contains(map.CatalogID)
        select map);

// iterate through each UPDATED relationship for this product
// and ADD it if necessary.
Product.CatalogProductMaps
    .AddRange(from catalogID in checkedCatalogs
        where !Product.CatalogProductMaps.Any(m => m.CatalogID == catalogID)
        select new Group{
            CatalogID = catalogID
    });


myDataContect.SubmitChanges();
```

So my question is:

**This can't be the *right* way to accomplish what I am doing. How can I improve the code for maintainability (and efficiency)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete process looks good to me, but checking for the existence of checked Products can be made more efficient using `Any()` rather than `Where()`:

```
if(Product.CatalogProductMap.Any(g => g.CatalogID == catalogID))
```

Comment: Works! Thanks. +1 for that. IMO `Any` is a terrible name for a boolean method. I'm really hoping there is something I can do with `Join` or `Intersect` to bring the 2 loops into one somehow (though I'm not sure that is the best approach either).